# viewDidLoad called twice, using navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, rootviewcontroller

My `ViewDidLoad` method on a `ViewController` is called twice, but only in a particular scenario. There are two view controllers which I need to present, one if user isn't logged in and the second if the user is logged in. I am using storyboard and have set a navigation controller as initial view controller in it.

In my `AppDelegate` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method I have populated `ViewControllers` array with the desired controller as below

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let navigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "navController") as! UINavigationController
if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: USERID) != nil {
    viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeVC_ID") as! HomeVC
} 
else {
    viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVC_ID") as! LoginVC
}
navigationController.viewControllers = [viewController] as! [UIViewController]
self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

`ViewDidLoad` method in `HomeVC` is called twice, whereas it's called just once for `LoginVC`.

I already tried searching through articles [viewDidLoad is called twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079602/viewdidload-is-called-twice) and [viewDidLoad getting called twice on rootViewController at launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081131/viewdidload-getting-called-twice-on-rootviewcontroller-at-launch) but couldn't corner the issue.

Comment: I think this is due to segue in Storyboard.

Comment: I have ticked "Is Initial View Controller" for navigation controller. No other segue used. If I remove it, it shows a black screen on loading.

Comment: if you setting root view controller programmatically then 
remove main interface from Deployment Info.

Comment: Maybe the `UITabViewController` is better for your UI design. You can hide tab button and control it by codes.

Comment: @JatinKathrotiya Removing "Main Storyboard file base name" presents a black screen after splash.

Comment: need to create window inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions 
`self.window = UIWindow(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height:  UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height))`

Comment: thanks @JatinKathrotiya Its working. but the issue remains, viewDidLoad still called twice.

Comment: if navigation controller has rootview controller inside  story board then remove it

Comment: you have set  embedded homeVC is initial ViewController  on storyboard. 
Do not embed you homeVc  in navigationController. Because When app launches it instantiated once from storyboard and second time from appDelegate.

Comment: I removed the navigation controller from storyboard. Implemented it programmatically from appdelegate. Still HomeVC viewDidLoad called twice on first launch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create your navigation view controller from the storyboard, this already contains it's `rootViewController` (which must not to be confused with the `rootViewController` of the `UIWindow`). I guess this is your `HomeVC` (in the storyboard). So, the storyboard magic already creates `HomeVC`, and you do not have to create it manually in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

If you have specify the storyboard as your main interface in the project's/target's properties, you do not need any creational code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and just let the framework perform the magic.

If you want to do this programatically, then - in the storyboard - you should remove the navigation controller, and create it manually (not via `instantiateViewController`) in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. You would also add the appropriate root view controller here (instantiated from the storyboard), maybe like this:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: USERID) != nil {
    viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeVC_ID") as! HomeVC
} else {
    viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVC_ID") as! LoginVC
}
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController:viewController)
self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: thanks. I removed navigation controller from storyboard and created the same manually, but the issue still repeats. On auto-login when control directly goes to the HomeVC, viewDidLoad is called just once, as desired. But in case of first time login, when it navigates from LoginVC, then its called twice.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend don't do any manual segue OR load view controller in app delegate. Use following piece of code in viewDidLoad of LoginView (hoping this is root view of your app always).

Use segue for login to homeview.

```
if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: USERID) != nil {
     self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "HomeViewIdentifier", sender: self)
}
```

Considering `HomeViewIdentifier` is a `segueId` for `LoginView` to `HomeView`.
Why I am suggesting this because you need to segue back to `loginView` when user logs out. In case you make `homeView` as `rootview` then where will you go in case of logout.