# Application running on iOS4.2 but not on iOS5

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have an application of which i have created .ipa file and tried to run the application on iOS5. If i run it on iOS 5, it works but when i try to run it on iOS4.2 it doesn't work. It opens up, shows black window and then back to home screen. I have tried things like deleting app, installing again, restarting phone, reseting it's setting.

I know most people face vice a versa situation. Let me know if any one of you have good solution for it.

Thank you,
Anks

Comment: What's the target iOS version of your project?

Comment: iOS 4.0...I actually tried now, when i select iOS4.3, it calls ViewDidLoad of viewcontroller twice and if i select iOS5 then it calls once and it works fine. Any solution for this?

Comment: might be a bug http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462481/why-is-viewdidload-called-twice-when-the-rootviewcontroller-property-of-uiwindow  or take a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081131/viewdidload-getting-called-twice-on-rootviewcontroller-at-launch

Answer (score 0):

Your only hope is the console, see what it says about why it is dying.   If that doesn't give any messages, stop it in the debugger in AplicationDidFinishLaunching, and step as far as you can...

The console though SHOULD have a message about why the app is terminating early.  Without knowing why, we cannot help further.

Comment: I actually tried now, when i select iOS4.3, it calls ViewDidLoad of viewcontroller twice and if i select iOS5 then it calls once and it works fine. Any solution for this?

Comment: That's what it does, not why it crashes.  What is the message when it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change your build target immediately before creating the .ipa? If so, do a clean build and then re-create the .ipa file again—that may fix your problem.