# Dismiss / Present Modal View Controller - again viewdidLoad is calling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview

I have faced one strange problem, when I click on the below button `informationBtn_clicked`. `InformationView` is coming.

### **MainView**

```
-(IBAction)informationBtn_clicked:(id)sender{
       InformationView  *obj_Info=[[InformationView alloc] initWithNibName:@"InformationView" bundle:nil];
       UINavigationController *navigationObj = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:obj_Info];
       [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navigationObj animated:YES];
}
```

### **NextView**

After below back btn clicked dismis the view controller;

```
-(void)btnBackClicked:(id)sender{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Here, my problem is when I dismiss the NextView, again calling main view the `viewDidLoad` method. My project is running in iOS 5, I am using ARC.

I am checking one way that is the Release the `obj_Info` but after result the same plz Help Me my English is very poor try to understand me.

Comment: this link may help you .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462481/why-is-viewdidload-called-twice-when-the-rootviewcontroller-property-of-uiwindow

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in the line:

```
UINavigationController *navigationObj = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:obj_Info];
```

you initialize the navigation controller with `obj_Info` as a root view controller. So when you dismiss the modal view controller, the navigation controller shows its root view controller, which happens to be the same as the modal view controller.

Try changing the line I mentioned with:

```
UINavigationController *navigationObj = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

The link he gave you shows there may be a bug in Apple's code that is related to your problem.  For now, maybe just workaround (e.g. in viewDidLoad, set a boolean, and then clear it in viewDidUnload; if it's set when you enter viewDidLoad, just return)